# JSON.Net Limit property string length when serializing

Tags: json.net

I want to limit the string length of property value when serializing to JSON using NewtonSoft JSON.NET. How can I do this? Is there a Serializer setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Inherit from `DefaultContractResolver`
2. Override `CreateProperties`
3. Modify property names after calling base implementation
4. Use your contract resolver when deserializing by setting `JsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver`